# Setting an instance variable using dependency

Tags: java, oop, dependency-injection

I am working on a project where I am trying to represent a Stock Portfolio. There is a class called `Position`. Also, there is another class called `Portfolio` and it's basically represents a set of positions along with additional instance variables/methods.

A single `Position` is stored in a plain `.txt` file. In order to read that file, I've created another class: `ReaderService`. In this class, necessary I/O operations are being performed and in the end, a `List<Position>` is being returned by the method called `readPositions()`.

`Portfolio` class depends on `ReaderService` in order to set its `positions` field, and I am injecting that dependency via constructor, that is constructor injection.

What I can't be sure about is that it seems like a bad practice to initialize a instance variable of `Portfolio` class in a setter method by using `ReaderService` dependency. Does this approach leads to any problems like tight coupling or smt else?

Here is the quick summary

`ReaderService`:

```
public class ReaderService {
    // necessary fields..

    // a method to extract all positions from the each line of .txt file.
    public ArrayList<Position> readPositions(){
        ArrayList<Position> positions = new ArrayList<>();
        ...
        /* for each line in the file, a new `Position` is being created
        and being added to `positions` after necessary file operations performed. */
        ...
            // Initializing a new position and adding it to the list
            Position position = new Position(...);
            positions.add(position);

         return positions;
    }
}
```

`Position` class:

```
public class Position {
    private String stockCode;
    private double balance;
    ...
    // There are more than two fields. Truncated it for the sake of the question.
    public Position(String stockCode, double balance, ...) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.balance = balance;
        ...
    }
}
```

And the class in question; `Portfolio` class:

```
public class Portfolio {
    private ArrayList<Position> positions;
    ...
    private final DataService dataService;
    private final ReaderService readerService;

    public Portfolio(DataService dataService, ReaderService readerService){
        this.dataService = dataService;
        this.readerService = readerService;
    }

    public ArrayList<Position> getPositions() {
        return positions;
    }

    // Check out this method. Is it a poor design?
    public void setPositions() {
        try {
            this.positions = readerService.readPositions();
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it correct thing to question the following:

*"A `ReaderService` is responsible to read the positions, but you are giving it the responsibility of creating list of positions for `Portfolio` class as well.'*

I mean do I break the *Single Responsibility* principle here?

I am also considering to make these service classes `static`.

Comment: does `Portfolio` do anything else? or just create several positions? As a novice, I think it would be better to make other class which execute `readerService.readPositions()` and create `Portfolio` instance with result.

Comment: Yes, portfolio class have additional responsibilities other than creating several positions. Coming back to your suggestion, that was my initial approach. It was like this in the main class.
`portfolio.setPositions(reader.readPositions());`

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readability, I answer here.

Rather than `setPositions()`, I would like to create with constructor. And create another class (or you can put it in main class as you said, but you may don't like it) as below.

```java
public class PortfolioService {
    private final DataService dataService;
    private final ReaderService readerService;

    public PortfolioService(DataService dataService, ReaderService readerService) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
        this.readerService = readerService;
    }

    public PortfolioService createPortfolio() {
         return new Portfolio(readerService.readPositions());
    }
}
```

then, `Portfolio` class will look like this.

```java
public class Portfolio {
    private final List<Position> positions;
    
    public Portfolio(List<Position> positions) {
         this.positions = positions;
    }
    
    // and do something else with positions
}
```